# How to create a new folder in Firebase when there is an existing folder named same in Firebase storage

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I am new to Firebase storage. I have a react app which accepts users to create their own folders with their names. In that folder, the app creates another folder with the trip they made to a city (let's say New York) and saves images in New York folder. Now the situation is what if the user again visits New York. The images are getting appended in the same folder but what I want is to create a new folder named which saves the images of his second trip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Folder names must be unique, so there is no way to create a second folder with the same name. This also makes sense: how would you address an individual folder, if two of them have the exact same name.

I'd consider adding some distinguishing marker to the folder name. For example, I timestamp my own photo folders/albums to ensure uniqueness. "2016-05 New York", "2016-11 New York", etc